# 'module' object has no attribute 'MutableMapping' issue in Caffe

Tags: protocol-buffers, caffe

My Caffe was running fine but then I installed Keras which gave the following error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

According to some advice, I updated Protobuf following these instructions of building from sources.
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md

And the result now is that neither Keras nor Caffe is running and I get the same error:

```
File "/home/myuser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 50, in <module>
from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

Of all the things, I would perhaps first try to uninstall the new version of Protobuf but how should I do it to go back to the previous state? And secondly, how to install the Protobuf so that Keras can also run?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be having two protobuf installations at the same time.